# Oracle 11g how to change nls_characterset only for one table or tablespace

Tags: oracle

Is it possible to change nls_characterset only for one table?
If it not, could I change or create new tablespace with different nls_characterset?

Comment: Why is your DB not UTF8?

Comment: I had to add new user/schema but I can't make any changes in db parameters. Tables which I had to create has EE8ISO8859P2 but DB is WE8MSWIN1252

Comment: No in Oracle the characterset is defined per database, not per table or tablespace (unlike in others RDBMS). Convert DB to `AL32UTF8`, then it will cover any client character set. Or use NVARCHAR/NCLOB/NCHAR data types.

Answer (score 1):

The simple answer: no. 
The character set is a characteristic of the entire database.